# Two Google Analytics Codes - both not collecting correctly

Tags: google-analytics

I have inherited a site which has two GA-UA codes.

These are setup like this

```
// first code 
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

//second code
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', {'name':'second'});
ga('second.send', 'pageview');
```

I have no idea why they are setup like this and indeed do not understand the syntax of the second tracking code

The following can be observed

**THE FIRST CODE**

- Custom events working and being successfully collected
- Linked successfully to Adwords
- Only has a few months of data and therefore we don't want to use this

**THE SECOND CODE**

- Does not record custom events
- Can't link to Adwords
- Has years of data attached to it that we want to use

The plan is to just use **the second code**

For complete brevity custom events are being triggered like this

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'contact-form', 'Goals');
```

My questions is this

"Because it has lots of historical data we wish to use code two but it is not collecting custom events. How do I get the second code to collect custom events so we can retire the first code? "

Answer (score 3):

If you use two trackers on one site you need to give a name to at least one of them, else the first tracker is overwritten when the second one is initialized.

Thus the syntax for your second piece of tracking code - when the tracker is initialized it is assigned a name, in your example "second".

If you want to send data to that tracker you need to prepend the assigned tracker name to the send call, in your example:

```
ga('second.send', 'event', 'Contact', 'contact-form', 'Goals');
```

That is why the second tracker does not receive your event tracking calls, they are only being sent to the first "unnamed" tracker (actually if a tracker name is not assigned it defaults to `t0`).

Also  do not think you can link an Adwords account to two different Google Analytics accounts, so. you'd need to unlink the first account and then link the second one.